# How can I pass vuex getter to module which isn't vuejs component, but keep it reactive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-reactivity

For example following code. I want to do some tasks repeatedly in my module and I depend on value of getter which doesn't get updated right now. How can I keep it in sync with my vuex state? Thank you.

Inside my `Vuex`:

```
import { start, stop } from './externa-module.js

START_ACTION ({getters}) {
   start(getters.myVuexGetters);
}
```

Inside my `external-module.js`

```
let myVuexGetter = null;

function doSomeStuffRepeatedly(){
  console.log(myVuexGetter);
}

export function start(importedGetter){
   myVuexGetter = importedGetter;
   doSomeStuffRepeatedly();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like I can't pass a single `getter` but a whole `getters` object which I get within the `action`. If anyone has a better answer I will be glad to learn it.